# Change value after page is called by link

Tags: angular

I have an area inside my application which shows different forms in dependency what the user wants to see. So I'm hiding/showing it by changing these 4 values:

```
this.createCustomer = false;
this.createCustomerBranch = false;
this.createHardwareTypes = false;
this.createStock = false;
```

so when the user now comes via my link:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="authService.isAdmin()" [routerLink]="['/admin']">Anlegen</a>
```

So by clicking this link, `this.createStock = false` should become `true` after the view has changed.

Do I have to toggle a function by clicking that link or how could I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry for the precedent mistake answer)
I don't understand why you are using

```
[routerLink]="['/admin']
```

I assume you are staying on the same page containing the forms ?

I would use :

```
<a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="authService.isAdmin()" 
(click)="createStock = !createStock">Anlegen</a>
```

And maybe use a button instead of a link ?
Hope that i understood the question correctly.

Comment: nope i'm not staying on the same page. The user is in his dashboard and has many options to choose what he wants to do. So if he now decides to create a stock, he clicks on that button and gets redirected into the admin area which contains many different forms on one page. And for showing the correct form, i have to set `this.createStock = true` after the view has loaded

Comment: ok then, simply use the double way data biding.
check this link : https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html
part "custom two way"